# How can I randomize my buttons in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm making a multiple choice quiz and I would like to make the positions of my Buttons random, how would you do this? I already made multiple arrays with Questions in them as you can see in the code below, but I don't know wheter I can leave my code as it is und make some modifications or if I have to rewrite it all to make the buttons random.

Thank you for your help, really.

Here's my code:

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView mImageView;
TextView mTextView;
TextView mAnswer;
TextView score;
TextView countDown;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton opt1;
RadioButton opt2;
RadioButton opt3;
RadioButton opt4;
Button check;

boolean answered = false;


public static final long COUNTDOWN_IN_MILLISECODS = 30000;
public CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
public long timeLeftInMilliseconds;

private ColorStateList textColorDefaultCd;
private ColorStateList textColorDefaultRb;

int scoreNumber = 0;
int questionNumber = 0;
int questionNumberTotal = 9;
int arrayNumber = -1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    mImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mTextView = findViewById(R.id.tvQ);
    mAnswer = findViewById(R.id.tvA);
    score = findViewById(R.id.tvScore);
    countDown = findViewById(R.id.tvCd);
    opt1 = findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    opt2 = findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    opt3 = findViewById(R.id.rb3);
    opt4 = findViewById(R.id.rb4);
    check = findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);
    radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.rG);

    textColorDefaultRb = opt1.getTextColors();

    textColorDefaultCd = countDown.getTextColors();

    shuffleQuestions();
    ShowNewQuestion();
    StartCountDown();

    check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            check.setText("Bestätigen");
            if (!answered) {
                if (opt1.isChecked() || opt2.isChecked() || opt3.isChecked() || opt4.isChecked()) {
                    CheckAnswer();
                    countDownTimer.cancel();
                    answered = true;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wählen Sie eine Antwort aus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else if (answered) {
                ShowNewQuestion();
                StartCountDown();
                answered = false;
            }
        }

    });
}


Objects q01 = new Objects(R.drawable.blauwahl, "Das Herz eines Blauwals ist ungefähr so groß wie...", "ein VW-Käfer", "Angela Merkels Privatjet", "ein VW-Käfer", "eine Vespa", "eine Wassermelone");
Objects q02 = new Objects(R.drawable.simbabwe, "Der südafrikanische Staat Simbabwe wurde 1980 unabhängig. Wie hieß das Land früher? ", "Rhodesien", "Botswana", "Rhodesien", "Südafrika", "Botsuana");
Objects q03 = new Objects(R.drawable.sonnenkoenig, " Der französische Sonnenkönig Ludwig XIV. herrschte lange Jahre über Frankreich. Wie viele? ", "72", "22", "52", "62", "72");
Objects q04 = new Objects(R.drawable.tempelberg, "Der Tempelberg in Jerusalem ist rund 144.000 Quadratmeter groß und beladen mit Mythen. Wer soll hier den ersten Mord der Menschheit begangen haben?", "Kain", "David", "Kain", "Herodes", "Joseph");
Objects q05 = new Objects(R.drawable.frauenkirche, "In welchem Jahr des Zweiten Weltkrieges wurde die Dresdener Frauenkirche zerstört? ", "1945", "1943", "1944", "1945", "1939");
Objects q06 = new Objects(R.drawable.kueste, "Welches dieser europäischen Länder hat die längste Küste?", "Griechenland", "Italien", "Griechenland", "Frankreich", "Türkei");
Objects q07 = new Objects(R.drawable.umriss, "Der Umriss welches inselreichen Landes ist hier zu sehen?", "Dänemark", "Dänemark", "Philippinen", "Kroatien", "Griechenland");
Objects q08 = new Objects(R.drawable.blitz, "Woran liegt es, dass man den Donner bei manchen Blitzen erst viel später hört als bei anderen?", "An der unterschiedlichen Entfernung der Blitze", "An der unterschiedlichen Entfernung der Blitze", "An der Stärke der elektrischen Entladungen", "An der Dichte des Regens", "An den heftigen Windböen");
Objects q09 = new Objects(R.drawable.biathlon, "Aus welchen beiden Disziplinen setzt sich ein Biathlon zuammen?", "Sportschießen und Skilanglauf", "Sportschießen und Skilanglauf", " Skispringen und Skilanglauf ", " Skilanglauf und Abfahrtslauf ", "Abfahrtslauf und Skispringen ");
Objects q10 = new Objects(R.drawable.licht, "In welcher physikalischen Einheit wird die Lichtstärke gemessen?", "Candela", "Joule", "Lumen", "Lux", "Candela");
Objects q11 = new Objects(R.drawable.sonne, "Welcher Planet unseres Sonnensystems ist am weitesten von der Sonne entfernt?", "Neptun", "Uranus", "Jupiter", "Neptun", "Saturn");

Objects[] objectsArray = new Objects[]{
        q01, q02, q03, q04, q05, q06, q07, q08, q09, q10, q11
};

public void shuffleQuestions() {

    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(objectsArray));
}

public void ShowNewQuestion() {
    if (questionNumber < questionNumberTotal) {

        opt1.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);
        opt2.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);
        opt3.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);
        opt4.setTextColor(textColorDefaultRb);

        radioGroup.clearCheck();
        answered = false;

        arrayNumber++;

        mTextView.setText(objectsArray[arrayNumber].getmQuestion());
        mImageView.setImageResource(objectsArray[arrayNumber].getmImages());
        opt1.setText(objectsArray[arrayNumber].getmOption1());
        opt2.setText(objectsArray[arrayNumber].getmOption2());
        opt3.setText(objectsArray[arrayNumber].getmOption3());
        opt4.setText(objectsArray[arrayNumber].getmOption4());
        mAnswer.setText(objectsArray[arrayNumber].getmAnswer());

        timeLeftInMilliseconds = COUNTDOWN_IN_MILLISECODS;
    } else {
        FinishQuiz();
    }
}




    if (opt1.isChecked()) {
        if (opt1.getText().equals(mAnswer.getText())) {
            scoreNumber++;
            questionNumber++;
            UpdateScore();
            countDownTimer.cancel();

        }

    } else if (opt2.isChecked()) {
        if (opt2.getText().equals(mAnswer.getText())) {
            scoreNumber++;
            questionNumber++;
            UpdateScore();
            countDownTimer.cancel();

        }

    }
    if (opt3.isChecked()) {
        if (opt3.getText().equals(mAnswer.getText())) {
            scoreNumber++;
            questionNumber++;
            UpdateScore();
            countDownTimer.cancel();

        }

    }
    else if (opt4.isChecked()) {
        if (opt4.getText().equals(mAnswer.getText())) {
            scoreNumber++;
            questionNumber++;
            UpdateScore();
            countDownTimer.cancel();

        } else {
            questionNumber++;
            countDownTimer.cancel();
        }
    }
```

Here I'm storing the objects:

```
public class Objects {

public int mImages;
public String mQuestion;
public String mAnswer;
public String mOption1;
public String mOption2;
public String mOption3;
public String mOption4;


public Objects(int mImages, String mQuestion, String mAnswer, String mOption1, String mOption2, String mOption3, String mOption4) {
    this.mImages = mImages;
    this.mQuestion = mQuestion;
    this.mAnswer = mAnswer;
    this.mOption1 = mOption1;
    this.mOption2 = mOption2;
    this.mOption3 = mOption3;
    this.mOption4 = mOption4;
    this.mAnswer = mAnswer;

}

public int getmImages() {

    return mImages;
}

public String getmQuestion() {
    return mQuestion;
}

public String getmAnswer() {
    return mAnswer;
}

public String getmOption1() {

    return mOption1;
}

public String getmOption2() {

    return mOption2;
}

public String getmOption3() {

    return mOption3;
}

public String getmOption4() {

    return mOption4;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Since your answers seem to be at the end of your arrays, and each question has four separate possible answers, you could try an example of:

```
String[] a01 = {"Angela Merkels Privatjet", "ein VW-Käfer", "eine Vespa", "eine Wassermelone};


Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(a01));
```

and then either change your Objects class to accept a String[] in place of your final four Strings, and set the class attributes equal to the array values, or vice versa with declaring the object arguments using the array String values.

e.g.

```
Objects q01 = new Objects(R.drawable.blauwahl, "Das Herz eines Blauwals ist ungefähr so groß wie...", "ein VW-Käfer", a01[0], a01[1], a01[2], a01[3]);
```

or

```
Objects q01 = new Objects(R.drawable.blauwahl, "Das Herz eines Blauwals ist ungefähr so groß wie...", "ein VW-Käfer", a01);
```

You need to declare some of the references in your onCreate method if doing this, and loop through the process of shuffling then creating or assigning the Objects object, before finally loading them into your Objects[] object.